Order by ASC doesn't return any item but order by DESC does
Any known explanation of this? Why Order By ASC doesn't return any item but order by DESC doesn't?
I am using postgres with pg_vector extension


SELECT
       langchain_pg_embedding.document,
       langchain_pg_embedding.embedding <=> (ARRAY [-0.021213598549366,  ...,           -0.03685509413480759])::vector AS distance
FROM langchain_pg_embedding
         JOIN langchain_pg_collection
              ON langchain_pg_embedding.collection_id = langchain_pg_collection.uuid
WHERE langchain_pg_embedding.collection_id = '3831f45b-ee1b-4009-afa4-c7b0e1aadda7'
ORDER BY distance DESC
LIMIT 1;

I am expecting in each query I will get one row (but different).


Do not use images, copy and paste as text into question text. 2) Run the queries in psql and see what you get. 3) Add to question text the Postgres version as well information about the client you are using including version.


Index might be corrupted. Try re-indexing

This is jetbrains client, even with PG admin we are seeing the same.

Normally, sorting only affects the order of the result set, not the content of the result set.
If the data is not large, it is recommended to remove limit 1 and see if the total amount of data is correct.
I feel that there is a sort order that causes the results to be null for the first few, and the query tool does not show it.

You need to read Order By and come back with an actual answer.

@AdrianKlaver Thank you very much for your answer. I read the document you linked, but I am so stupid that I did not find my answer wrong. Could you please point it out?

From the link: If neither is specified, the default behavior is NULLS LAST when ASC is specified or implied, and NULLS FIRST when DESC is specified. Your answer concludes with  I feel that there is a sort order that causes the results to be null for the first few, ... which is contrary to what the ordering in the question is doing.
